# Vuejs load directive dynamicly via data property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

From the axios i am getting `<test-component></test-component>` and i want to add this as a component to the `example-component`

The output is now

```
<test-component></test-component>
```

In stead off

```
test component
```

Is that possible and how can i achieve that?

App.js:

```
import Example from './components/ExampleComponent.vue'
import Test from './components/Test.vue'
Vue.component('example-component', Example)
Vue.component('test-component', Test)
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

ExampleComponent:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        {{test}}
    </div>
</template>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            test: ''
        }
    },
    created() {
        axios.get('/xxxx')
            .then(function (response) {
                this.test = response.data.testdirective
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            })
            .finally(function () {
                // always executed
            });
    }
}
```

TestComponent:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        test component
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only).
You need to recompile the template you get from the server. Or use server-side rendering. Meaning: It is not possible with the run-time only build.

Comment: You should change the use of *directive* in this context to *component* as directives in vue have different purposes and are only applied as attributes e.g. `v-for`, `v-if` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with the *runtime-only* build of vuejs. You will need to configure your setup to use the full build of vuejs. The [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only) specify the setup with some build tools like webpack.

Once the vue template compiler is integrated in the runtime. You can use your current approach to render the component dynamicaly.

There is also another approach to this, which is a bit simpler.
You can use [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component v-if="name" :is="name"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestComponent from "./TestComponent.vue"
import Test2Component from "./Test2Component.vue"
import Test3Component from "./Test3Component.vue"

export default {
  component: {
    TestComponent,
    Test2Component,
    Test3Component
  },

  data() {
    return {
      name: undefined
    }
  },

  created() {
    axios.get('/xxxx')
        .then(function (response) {
            // where 'response.data.testdirective' is the components name
            // without <> e.g. "test-component", "test1-component" or "test2-component"
            this.name= response.data.testdirective
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
            this.name = undefined
        })
        .finally(function () {
            // always executed
        });
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, instead of compiling the components on the fly, I import them to get pre-compiled and bind them dynamically via `name`. No additional setup required!